# Unable to create pvc.yaml file

Tags: yaml, kubectl, kubernetes-pvc

I have created a `pvc.yaml` file but I am not able to add pvc to cluster as, I am facing an error for `pvc.yaml` file.

My `pvc.yaml` file content:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: local-device-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

After creating pvc, I am using this cmd:

```
kubctl create -f pvc.yaml
```

and I get this error:

> Error: error parsing pvc.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 8: could not find expected ':'

I have used an online yaml validator but I am still unable to solve this error.

I want my yaml file to be created and solve the error syntax error:

> could not find expected ':'

Comment: Did you try to format pvc.yaml file?

Comment: Yes, tried if yaml is correct then it is showing invalid yaml by kubernetes.